# Creating a second object makes functions of class not work anymore

Tags: java, class, processing

I'm trying to write a class that shows vectors. If I create one vector object everything works as intended. In my example code the object `lin1` gets drawn with the help of the `draw()` function.

If I now create a second vector object, the (unchanged) draw-function doesnt do anything anymore, even though the object itself is unchanged. It's the same the other way around: Is the second object the only one existing, then it can be drawn, but only as long as `lin1` doesnt exist.

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

```
vector lin;
vector lin2;

void setup()
{
  size(500,500);
  background(255);
  cenX = width/2;
  cenY = height/2;
  noLoop();
}

void draw()
{
  coordSys();
  lin = new vector(0,0,100,100);
  lin2 = new vector(0,0,-200,-200);
  lin.draw();
  lin2.draw();
  lin.getAll();
}

class vector
{
  float x1,y1,x2,y2;
  float length;
  float angle;
  float gegenK, anK;

  vector(float nx1, float ny1, float nx2, float ny2)
  {
    translate(cenX,cenY);
    x1 = nx1; y1 = -ny1; x2 = nx2; y2 = -ny2; 
    strokeWeight(2);
    // Gegenkathete
    gegenK = ny2 - ny1;
    // Ankathete
    anK = x2 - x1;
    // length and angle
    length = sqrt(sq(anK) + sq(gegenK));
    angle = winkel(gegenK, anK);
  }

  void draw()
  {
    stroke(0);
    line(x1,y1,x2,y2);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't call `lin2.getAll()`?

Comment: Can you show the source code to `stroke()` and `line()`? What does `stroke(0)` do?

Comment: Those are Processing-internal functions. Line draws a line and stroke sets the color of the line.

Comment: @Ishnark: oh sorry, the getall function just prints out the coordinates of the start and end point of the vectors. They are correct in both vectors, they just dont get drawn.

Comment: In the draw() function, do you need to change it to reference the calling 'line', as in:  this.line(x1,y1,x2,y2);  ?   otherwise, it seems like it is only working with 1 line() function.  HTH, Jim

Comment: @Jim: I tried it with line(this.x1,this.y1,this.x2,this.y2); same result. this.line gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use standard naming conventions when writing code. Specifically, your class should be `Vector` with an upper-case V. Also, please post your code in the form of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that compiles and runs.

Anyway, the first call in your `Vector()` constructor is this:

```
translate(cenX,cenY);
```

This moves the origin of the window halfway across the window. When you do this once, this simply makes your drawing calls relative to the center of the window. But when you do this twice, it moves the origin to the bottom-right corner of the window, so all of your drawings are moved off the edge of the screen.

To fix your problem, you need to move this line so it only happens once (perhaps at the beginning of the `draw()` function) instead of every single time you draw a `Vector`. Another way to approach this would be to use the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions to avoid this stacking of window translations.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!